# GitStats doesn't recognise Gnuplot (Windows)

Tags: python, git, gnuplot

I tried to set up [GitStats](https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats) but I can't seem to get it working on Windows 10 with Git Bash

I've added an environment variable to "C:\gnuplot\bin" for Gnuplot

Gnuplot installed:

```
$ gnuplot --version
gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 7
```

GitStats:

```
$  python gitstats ../ ../stats/
'C:\gnuplot\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[0.04700] >> C:\gnuplot\bin --version
gnuplot not found
```

How can I get it working?

Comment: You have not set your environmental variable correctly, This is the indication ```C:\gnuplot\bin --version``` of the same

Comment: gnuplot installer for windows actually provides an option to add the environmental variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [gitstats](https://github.com/hoxu/gitstats/blob/55c5c285558c410bb35ebf421245d320ab9ee9fa/gitstats#L33-L37) scripts includes:

```
# By default, gnuplot is searched from path, but can be overridden with the
# environment variable "GNUPLOT"
gnuplot_cmd = 'gnuplot'
if 'GNUPLOT' in os.environ:
    gnuplot_cmd = os.environ['GNUPLOT']
```

That means you need to set GNUPLOT to the gnuplot *executable*, not its parent folder (`bin`).

```
set GNUPLOT=C:\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe
```